# Change log4j2 ROOT logger programmatically, add AppenderRef + ThreadContextMapFiler values

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I want to change my logging configuration during application runtime. Under some circumstances I want to add an AppenderRef to my existing root logger. See my **configuration**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="log42programaticaly">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [NORMAL] [%X{TRACER}] %msg%n%xEx</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <Console name="traceAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%-5level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [TRACE ] [%X{TRACER}] %msg%n%xEx</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <ThreadContextMapFiler onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" operator="OR">
                <KeyValuePair key="ID" value="XX"/>
                <!-- <KeyValuePair key="ID" value="XX"/> -->
            </ThreadContextMapFiler>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL" additivity="FALSE">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" level="INFO" />
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="traceAppender" level="ALL" />  -->
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

At startup there is only the root logger and a reference to the consoleAppender.

First thing I want to achieve is to add a reference to my traceAppender, during runtime.

Another thing is that I want to add new KeyValuePairs to my ThreadContextMapFilter. It would also be okay to create a new ThreadContextMapFilter if this would be to complicated.

I already have a little code but it doesn't work:

**Static method in seperate class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter.Result;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.KeyValuePair;

public class LogHandler {
   public static final String TRACE_APPENDER = "traceAppender";
   public static final String ID = "ID";
   public static final String LAYOUT_STR = "%-5level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [TRACELOGGER ] [%X{TRACER}] %msg%n%xEx";

   public static void enableTrace(LoggerContext ctx, final String traceValue) {

      Configuration log4jCfg = ctx.getConfiguration();
      LoggerConfig rootLoggerCfg = log4jCfg.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

      ConsoleAppender traceAppender = null;
      if (rootLoggerCfg.getAppenders().size() > 0 && rootLoggerCfg.getAppenders().containsKey(TRACE_APPENDER) && rootLoggerCfg.getAppenders().get(TRACE_APPENDER) instanceof ConsoleAppender) {
         traceAppender = (ConsoleAppender) rootLoggerCfg.getAppenders().get(TRACE_APPENDER);
      } else {
         // ... should create new?
      }

      List<KeyValuePair> filterValues = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair>();
      if (null != rootLoggerCfg) {
         filterValues.add(new KeyValuePair(ID, traceValue));

         KeyValuePair[] tmp = filterValues.toArray(new KeyValuePair[filterValues.size()]);
         ThreadContextMapFiler f = ThreadContextMapFiler.createFilter(tmp, "or", Result.ACCEPT, Result.DENY);
         traceAppender.addFilter(f);
         log4jCfg.addAppender(traceAppender);
         ctx.reconfigure();
         ctx.updateLoggers();
      }
   }
}
```

**Call:**

```
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
LogHandler.trace(ctx, id.toString());
```

My environment: Tomcat7 + log4j2 (2.0) on linux x64.

Regards, Sebastian

Comment: I'm glad you posted the code sample - I couldn't find how I was supposed to get the root's LoggerConfig in log4j2 anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically change the target log file with the configuration mentioned here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files

You can define multiple routes in the configuration, and put values in the ThreadContext map that determine which log file subsequent events in this thread get logged to.

Comment: Hi Remko, I just tried the mentioned solution but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The route  with no key creates a file but the filename is evaluated only once. See my config https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab2b71880e62ade43765#file-gistfile1-xml

Comment: Are you saying that rollover does not work in combination with the RoutingAppender?

Comment: No, the file will be created for the route "<Route>" (see posted link before) but only for one value <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:TARGET_DEFINITION_ID}" fileName="/home/scams02/trace-${ctx:TARGET_DEFINITION_ID}.log" ... regardsles of the value of TARGET_DEFINITION_ID always the first created file will be used.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour. You can control the file name dynamically by changing the value of the routing key in the map. So, if you have `<Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">`, then use `<Route> <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}" fileName="logs/other-${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}.log" ...` You need to use the routing key in the file name. The route with no key will not be dynamic.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the useful advise! I just solved it :-) I added another variable to the threadcontext which now will be displayed in the logfiles %X{JOBIDENT} and another which is used as pattern <Routes pattern="$${ctx:TRACER}"> and also as dynamic logfilename <Route>
    <File name="rollingTraceAppender-${ctx:TRACER}" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/trace_${ctx:TRACER}.log">